# Reording a bar plot in R from lowest to highest without ggplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the code for my barplot, but I want to now order its values from lowest to highest, but I would like to do this without using ggplot because I am using a vector not a dataframe. This is in language R by the way. Thank you!

Comment: It's easy enough to convert a vector to a data frame? If you just want to use base R, that's fine. Also: please provide some example data and your code, both as plain text.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(1001)
x <- sample(1:10, 10)
names(x) <- LETTERS[1:10]    x

A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J 
7  3 10  8  9  4  5  1  6  2
```

Use `sort` to plot in order.

```
barplot(sort(x))
```

[image]